# Как выбрать из бд друзей и их друзей

Tags: php, mysql

Имею систему добавления друзей на сайте, необходимо добавить в настройку аккаунта новый пункт в настройку кто может отправлять заявку в друзья. На данный момент есть только настройка ВСЕ и НИКТО необходимо добавить пункт ДРУЗЬЯ ДРУЗЕЙ. Значение которое настраивается в настройках профля помещается в таблицу setting где id_user равен моему айди и столбец friends = 3. Необходимо написать обработку на PHP которая переберёт всех друзей друзей и если есть значение в котором друг является моим другом то поставить в переменную $access = 'Y'. Сам код не обязательно писать, напишите примерное понимание как это можно реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обход_дерева
Если код не нужен - этого должно быть достаточно

Comment: *примерное понимание как это можно реализовать* [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть таблица `friends` с полями `guy_id` и `friend_id`, которая печесляет идентифиакторы всех друзей (friend_id) для конкретного пользователя (guy_id).
Предполагается, что для каждой записи `guy_id = A, friend_id = B` существует запись `guy_id = B, friend_id = A`

Тогда в общем случае получение списка всех друзей и друзей друзей будет выглядеть как

```sql
select t.friend_id 
  from friends t 
  where t.guy_id = <guy_id>
union
select distinct f.friend_id 
  from friends t
    join friend f 
      on f.guy_id = t.friend_id
  where t.guy_id = <guy_id>
```

Но, мне кажется, задачу правильно ставить не то, как выбрать всех друзей друзей, а как именно реализовать проверку в момент когда кто-то кому-то собирается что-то написать.

```
... 
  case
    when exists (
      select * 
        from friends t 
        where t.guy_id = <кому_пишут_id>
           and (t.friend_id = <кто_пишет_id>
                or t.friend_id in ( 
                  select f.friend_id 
                    from friends f 
                    where f.guy_id = <кто_пишет_id>
                 )
               )

      ) 
    then <можно писать> 
    else <нельзя писать>
  end
```

В чём разница двух подходов: если в первом случае СУБД выбирет всех друзей, и затем для каждого друга выбирает список всех его друзей, затем устраняя дубликаты, то во втором случае СУБД выбирает только 2 списка: список друзей того, кто пишет, и список друзей того, кому пишут. Затем задача сводится к обнаружению существования пересечения этих списков, что является относительно дешёвой операцией.